# Show all notes in grid pattern Android Studio

Tags: android

I'm working on a note taking app using Android Studio, and I'm using SQLite to store the notes. Currently in the MainActivity, all the notes are shown using a list view. I want to show the notes in a grid pattern with each grid having a container which contains part of the note's text and also a title and date created below the partial note text. How would I do this? Below is a picture to give an idea of what I mean. Just imagine that the images in that picture partially show some of the note's text instead.

[a busy cat http://c1.soft112.com/images/06/2e/htc-scribble/pad_screenshot_240x180.png](http://c1.soft112.com/images/06/2e/htc-scribble/pad_screenshot_240x180.png)

Would I use a grid view and then put a relative layout in each grid to structure the partial note text, title and date created? Also do I just store the partial note text in a simple text view?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes - create adapter like in **ListView** next in **getView** in Adapter inflate view for grid element, there You can use **RelativeLayout**. TextView can be used also for complex texts not only single line text.

If You are interested check RecyclerView which can be used as grid or list, it can be changed dynamically , for example if small screen - list - if big screen grid.

If you need partial text then use String method - **YourString.substring(0, 20)**

Example of getView in adapter:

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {
        // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        LayoutInflater vi;
        vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.your_grid_view,null);


    }

    YourClassRepresentGridElement current=getItem(position);
    /* in getItem you should get element from database or from
      collection which was generated from database
    */


    //here do work with your view set it an values from object
    //example
    ((TextView)convertView.findElementById("text")).setText(current.text.substring(0,20));

   //remember using findElementById on every getView is not good practice - read about holder

    return convertView;


}
```

Comment: Could you reword the first part to your answer? It's a bit unclear

Answer (score 0):

try using base Adapter

activity_main.xml: Layout for MainActivity.java. For this demo application, it would contain only a ListView.

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvCustomList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**layout_list_item.xml: Layout for list items to be displayed in ListView. In this list, each list item will display an ImageView and two TextView.**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/star1" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Title" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvDesc"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Description" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Create model class**

**ListData.java: This model class contains two String type values for Title and Description. imgResId is for displaying image in list items.**

```
    package pcsalt.example.customlistviewdemo;

/*
 * ListData class will hold data for displaying in ListView
 * */
public class ListData {

        String Description;
        String title;
        int imgResId;

        public String getDescription() {
                return Description;
        }

        public void setDescription(String description) {
                Description = description;
        }

        public String getTitle() {
                return title;
        }

        public void setTitle(String title) {
                this.title = title;
        }

        public int getImgResId() {
                return imgResId;
        }

        public void setImgResId(int imgResId) {
                this.imgResId = imgResId;
        }

}
```

**Inherit BaseAdapter and modify according to functionality
MyBaseAdapter.java: Create a custom BaseAdapter to inflate the ListView items with layout_list_item.xml layout.**

```
 package pcsalt.example.customlistviewdemo;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    ArrayList myList = new ArrayList();
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    Context context;


    public MyBaseAdapter(Context context, ArrayList myList) {
        this.myList = myList;
        this.context = context;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return myList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public ListData getItem(int position) {
        return myList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        MyViewHolder mViewHolder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_list_item, parent, false);
            mViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(mViewHolder);
        } else {
            mViewHolder = (MyViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        ListData currentListData = getItem(position);

        mViewHolder.tvTitle.setText(currentListData.getTitle());
        mViewHolder.tvDesc.setText(currentListData.getDescription());
        mViewHolder.ivIcon.setImageResource(currentListData.getImgResId());

        return convertView;
    }

    private class MyViewHolder {
        TextView tvTitle, tvDesc;
        ImageView ivIcon;

        public MyViewHolder(View item) {
            tvTitle = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
            tvDesc = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.tvDesc);
            ivIcon = (ImageView) item.findViewById(R.id.ivIcon);
        }
    }
}



   if (convertView == null) {
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_list_item, parent, false);
    mViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(convertView);
    convertView.setTag(mViewHolder);
} else {
    mViewHolder = (MyViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
}
```

**In this code, we are checking if convertView is already initialized or not. If not, then inflate the list item layout, create ViewHolder object and save it in a tag of convertView. If convertView is already initialized, then retrieve the instance of ViewHolder from the convertView tag.
This is required to reuse the memory, which was already instantiated for previous list item. If this is not done, then for each new item getting displayed in the list will instantiate its own memory. And, it may cause OutOfMemoryException.
Populate BaseAdapter with data
To populate data into BaseAdapter, we will pass a List of model class from MainActivity.java**

```
    package pcsalt.example.customlistviewdemo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ListView lvDetail;
    Context context = MainActivity.this;
    ArrayList myList = new ArrayList();

    String[] title = new String[]{
            "Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3", "Title 4",
            "Title 5", "Title 6", "Title 7", "Title 8"
    };
    String[] desc = new String[]{
            "Desc 1", "Desc 2", "Desc 3", "Desc 4",
            "Desc 5", "Desc 6", "Desc 7", "Desc 8"
    };
    int[] img = new int[]{
            R.drawable.star1, R.drawable.star2, R.drawable.star3, R.drawable.star4,
            R.drawable.star5, R.drawable.star6, R.drawable.star7, R.drawable.star8
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        lvDetail = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvCustomList);
        // insert data into the list before setting the adapter
        // otherwise it will generate NullPointerException  - Obviously
        getDataInList();
        lvDetail.setAdapter(new MyBaseAdapter(context, myList));
    }

    private void getDataInList() {
        for (int i = 0; i &lt; title.length; i++) {
            // Create a new object for each list item
            ListData ld = new ListData();
            ld.setTitle(title[i]);
            ld.setDescription(desc[i]);
            ld.setImgResId(img[i]);
            // Add this object into the ArrayList myList
            myList.add(ld);
        }
    }

}
```

https://github.com/krrishnaaaa/CustomListViewDemo